# How to count the number of odd numbers in a Hailstone Sequence using C++

Tags: c++

I am currently enrolled in an Into to C++ class in college. One of the assignments requires students to create a C++ program that prompts the user for an integer then displays the hailstone sequence beginning from the value inputed and ending at 1. In addition, it is also required that the program outputs the following: 
1. the length of the sequence 
2. the largest number in the sequence 
3. the number of odd integers in the sequence 
4. the longest sequence from 1 to the inputted value n

I have completed the all of the requirements, except for the 3rd item. Below is a copy of the function I had created to accomplish this task.

```
int oddCont(int n)
{

    int count = 0; 
    while (n != 1) 
    {
        if (!isEven(n))
        {
            count++; 
        }
        n = nextVal(n);
    }

    return count; 
}
```

The issue that I am having is that this function returns one less than the correct number. For example, if there are four odd numbers, it prints 3. I have also discovered that the issue, specifically, is that the function does not count the last number in the sequence, 1, as an odd integer. So, if I were to get the hailstone sequence beginning with 7 and ending with one, it would count all the odd numbers, but 1 (7, 11, 17, 13, and 5). I am, however, unsure how to amend this.

I would really appreciate any advice to help resolve this issue. Also, for your convenience, I will include the definitions for the other two functions invoked within the above one.

```
//returns true if n is even and false otherwise
bool isEven(int n) 
{
    if (n % 2 == 0)
    {
        return true; 
    }
    else 
    {
        return false; 
    }

}

//returns hailstone sequence value that proceeds n
int nextVal(int n)
{
    if (isEven(n))
    {
        return n/2;
    }
    else 
    {
        return 3 * n + 1; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Notice that in your loop `n = nextVal(n);` comes _after_ `if (!isEven(n)){}`. Therefore when you go from `2` to `1` and then the loop's condition is broken (`while (n != 1)`), you don't execute that `if (!isEven(n))` one last time.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist If you are suggesting that the OP switch the order of the logic, this is problematic because it will sometimes give the correct answer and sometimes not, depending on whether `n` is odd or even itself. On the other hand, the given solution is off by one **every** time, so the fix is simple.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I was looking to structure the code more in the form of a loop with a header, a la `count = !isEven(n); while(){ /* ... */ count += !isEven(n);}`, but your approach is very correct too and indeed simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Since the loop stops as soon as `n` becomes 1, you **know** that there is **always** one more odd number. So the change is simple:

```
return count + 1;
```

Note that you can reduce your `isEven()` function to a single line:

```
return n % 2 == 0;
```